# How to write to text file using onClick?

Tags: javascript, php, input, file-io, onclick

I created a simple php/javascript/html page.

It works like this:

- It gets the information from an SQL Query;
- It uses a `for` to display all the information on a table;
- At each line, there are two buttons. Each button calls a function, that writes a message in the text file, along with the information on that particular line.

My problem:
Whenever I refresh the page, instead of waiting for me to click a button and then write the message, everything is being written in the file.

I have already tried to take the function calls to outside of the `for` loop, but that didn't solve. I believe that, since they are inside the loop, every time I refresh the page, both buttons "are clicked".

I also tried to change the type from button to submit, but it didn't work.

Here is the code that I'm using it:

```
<?php   
for($i=0;$i<count($aux);$i++){
?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $i+1; // Simple counter, to have everything in order ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $aux[$i]['NAME']; // Displays the name?></td>
 <td><?php echo $aux[$i]['INFO']; // Display some information?></td>

<script>

function First_Message(){
 <?php  // If the first button is pressed, then this function is called
 $contents .= "Message: ".trim($aux[$i]['NAME'])." message #1 ".date("H:i:s");
 $success = file_put_contents("file.txt", $contents);
 ?>
 }
</script>

<script>
function Second_Message(){
 <?php  If the second button is pressed, then this function is called
 $contents .= "Please,: ".trim($aux[$i]['NAME'])." message #2 ".date("H:i:s");
 $success = file_put_contents("file.txt", $contents);
 ?>
 }
</script>

<!-- Creates the first button -->

<td><input type="button" value="message_1" name = "balcao" onClick = "First_Message()" /></td>

<!-- Creates the second button -->

<td><input type="button" value="message_2" name = "balanca" onClick = 
"Second_Message()" /></td>

</tr>
<?php   
} // End Loop
?>
```

I expect the output to be only one line of message being written on the text file, and this message to be what I decide based on the click on any of those two buttons.

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or/and tell me an alternative to what I'm currently doing it with onClick, which I think is the problem, I would really appreciate.

Feel free to ask for more info if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can not** mix javascript and php functions in this way.

The first solution that came to me was a simple ajax query.

What is ajax?

> **AJAX** is a technique for creating fast and dynamic web pages. AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging small amounts of data with the server behind the scenes. This means that it is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page.

Simple code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' && isset($_POST['text'])):
    $output = '';
    $filename = 'file.txt';
    if (!file_exists($filename)):
        $myfile = fopen($filename, "w");
    endif;
    file_put_contents($filename, $_POST['text']);   
    $output = array("File content created");
    die(json_encode($output));
else:
?>

<?php
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++):
?>
    <button id="button" type="button" value="Clicked button <?php echo $x; ?>">A am button <?php echo $x; ?></button>
<?php
endfor;
?>

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>     
<script>
$(document).on('click','#button',function(e) {
    var my_text = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json",
        url: window.location.href,
        data: "text=" + my_text,
        beforeSend: function (data) {
            alert('Sending');
        },
        success: function (data) 
        {
            alert('Success');

        },
        error: function (data) 
        {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });     
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you @G3ck. Although your code works and it absolutely looks as an improvement from what I was thinking about, my issue is still the fact that the buttons still need to be inside the `for` loop. Whenever I try to do that, it always gets the same value. How can I make so that when clicked the "text=" + my_text gets only the info on a certain line?

Comment: @Lucas Lisboa just edited code in my answer. You can place your text inline `value="Clicked button <?php echo $x; ?>"`

Comment: If this answer is useful for You, please mark it as correct.

Comment: Thank you. The update you did solves my problem. Thanks for your attention and patience.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Php is executed in server side, while javascript (and html) is executed in browser side.
You must send, from browser (with javascript, in ajax for example) to server, and treat it in php.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. This seems to be the case, the other answer also pointed out that I need to use ajax to solve this case.